Conditional Mapping with MapStruct
Here below is the logic I need to implement my converter:
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public interface VehicleConverter {

    private final BicycleConverter bicycleConderer;
    private final CarConverer carConverter;
    private final PlaneConverer planeConverter;

    default Vehicle convert(final VehicleDTD vehicle) {
        if (!vehicle.hasMotor() && vehicle.power != ZERO) {
           throw new PowerCanBeSpecifiedOnlyForVehiclesWithMotor();
        }
        return switch(vechicle.getType) {
            BICYLCE -> bicycleConverter.convert(vehicle);
            CAR -> carConverter.convert(vehicle);
            PLANE-> planeConverter.covert(vehicle);
            default -> null;
       }
    }
}

Class Vehicle has several specialized subclasses, one for each supported vehicle type. Each vehicle has its own Mapper... and I'd like to have something like this:
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
   uses={BicycleConverter.class, CarConverter.class, PlaneConverter.class})
public interface VehicleConverter {

    /*
    Is it possible to let MapStruct use the correct specialized converter
    depending on `vehicle.type`?
    */
    Vehicle convert(final VehicleDTD vehicle);

    @BeforeMapping
    default void checkVehicle(final VehicleDTD vehicle) {
        if (!vehicle.hasMotor() && vehicle.power != ZERO) {
           throw new PowerCanBeSpecifiedOnlyForVehiclesWithMotor();
        }
    }
}

Given the new version here above, is it possible to let MapStruct use the correct specialized converter depending on vehicle.type?
